# Making AJAX calls with Python

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, ajax

I am trying to get the value of the `href` attribute of an anchor element from a web page using a self-made Python script. However, all of the contents of the `div` element inside which the anchor element sits are received by the web page by using AJAX jQuery calls when the web page initially loads. The `div` element contains about 90% of the web page's content. How can I get the contents of the `div` element and then the value of the `href` attribute of the anchor element?

Later, after I get the value of the 'href' attribute, I want to get the contents of the web page that the link points to. But unfortunately, that call is also made with AJAX (jQuery). When I click on this in the web browser, the address of the web page does not change in the address bar, which means that the contents of the web page that is received is loaded into the same web page (inside the above mentioned `div`) element.

After I get this, I will be using BeautifulSoup to parse the web page. So, how will I be able to do this with Python? What sort of modules do I need to use? And what is the general pseudo-code required?

By the way, the anchor element has an `onclick` event handler that triggers the corresponding jQuery function that loads the contents into the `div` element inside the web page.

Moreover, the anchor element is not associated with an id, if its needed for the solution.

Comment: The 'anchor' element, since it sits inside the 'div' element, is also fetched using ajax jquery call when the page loads for the first time.

Comment: so, just to clarify, you are scraping a page with Python and, unlike a browser, the ajax call hasn't happened so you don't see all the html you need to carry out the scraping?

Comment: @JLPeyret Yes, thats exactly what my problem is. Since the web page is not static, so I dont know beforehand what element to scrap...

Comment: agree with citruspi - you need a browser that will execute that ajax call. but one word of caution - headless browsers can be quirky with newer JS features - for example, phantomjs would error out on *bind* until the recent v2 - so you need to make sure that they will work with your pages of interest before investing too much time on them.  on that note phantompy says its status is abandoned.

Comment: Would you consider upvoting and/or accepting the below answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd want to use a headless web browser. Take a look at [Ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) or [phantompy](https://github.com/niwibe/phantompy).

---

I just realized that [phantompy](https://github.com/niwibe/phantompy) is no longer being actively developed, so here's an example with [Ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/).

I created an HTML page which is blank. Some JavaScript adds a couple links to a `div`.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="links">
            <!-- Links go here -->
        </div>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var div = document.getElementById('links');

        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.innerHTML = 'DuckDuckGo';
        link.setAttribute('href', 'http://duckduckgo.com');

        div.appendChild(link);
    </script>
</html>
```

So if you were to scrape the page right now with Beautiful Soup using something like `soup.find_all('a')` you wouldn't get an links, because there aren't any.

But we can use a headless browser to render the content for us.

```py
>>> from ghost import Ghost
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>
>>> ghost = Ghost()
>>>
>>> ghost.open('http://localhost:8000')
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(ghost.content)
>>> soup.find_all('a')
[<a href="http://duckduckgo.com">DuckDuckGo</a>]
```

If you have to do something like clicking a link to change the content on the page, you could also do this. Check out the [Sample use case](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/#sample) on the project's website.

Comment: Hello, Can you please elaborate your answer please? I am currently looking at the links that you mentioned and they seem to be good, but however since I am new to the Ghost module, it will be highly helpful if you will be able to elaborate your answer.

Comment: @Python_user I've added some sample code and a link to an example which I think is relevant to what you're looking for.